# JPanel Black screen because of componentResize and long repaint command

Tags: java, swing

The problem is obvious: I have a big paint command with a very large for loop and a componentResized that runs the paint command a huge amount of time, which makes my JPanel a black screen and unable to exit even when I press the x button(I must terminate it on eclipse), represented here:

```
package Testing;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class DrawTest extends JPanel implements ComponentListener {
public DrawTest(){
    this.addComponentListener(this);
}
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
            int gridsize=8;
    double width=getWidth()/gridsize;
    for(double i=0;i<=getWidth();i+=width){
        System.out.println("1");
        g.drawLine((int)i,0,(int)i,getHeight());
    }

    double height=getHeight()/gridsize;
    for(double i=0;i<=getHeight();i+=height){
        System.out.println("2");
        g.drawLine(0,(int)i,getWidth(),(int)i);
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Fill all the squares with Ls");
        DrawTest FillSquare=new DrawTest();
        frame.add(FillSquare);
        frame.setExtendedState( frame.getExtendedState()|frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
        frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
           ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    //...Perform a task...

                    System.out.println("Reading SMTP Info.");
                }
            };
            Timer timer = new Timer(100 ,taskPerformer);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I googled the problem and looked it up on stackoverthrow, and what came up was to use the Timer which prevent the componentResize to run a crazy amount of times when the user resizes the screen, but after implementing it, as shown in the code, it still doesn't seem to be working. I don't know if I did it wrong or what, it is my first time using it. After playing around and testing with the System.out.println();, I seem to run into another problem. The paint command's second loop seem to be going infinitely after the user moves the frame.[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four things:

- Don't do `for(int i=1;i<=100000;i++){` inside the `paint` method.  Paint methods should return as fast as possible, otherwise, you end up with issues like you have right now.  Consider buffering the output so you don't have update it repeatedly and waste time.
- Call `super.paint` before doing any custom painting
- Override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` (and call `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting)
- Every-time `componentResized` is called, you're creating another `Timer`, so if it get's called 100 times, you're creating a 100 `Timer`s, this won't scale well

As a possible solution, you don't "need" to use `ComponentListener`, I tend to just override `invalidate`, but you will get similar results using either.

You should use a `BufferedImage` to represent what you want painted, this way, if the `paint` method is called for some reason other then the component been resized, you can just paint the `BufferedImage` and not worry about having to recreate the entire state from scratch.

You only need a single `Timer`, which is restarted each time you are notified that the the component has changed.

When the `Timer` is triggers the `ActionListener`, you would invalidate the current buffer and regenerate it.  The example I've provided uses a `SwingWorker` to off load the work to a back ground thread, which will allow the UI to remain responsive while the buffer is updated it.  You could display a little message in the `paintComponent` method when the buffer is `null` stating that the output is been regenerated, as an idea

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DrawTest extends JPanel {

    private Timer resizeTimer;
    private BufferedImage buffer;
    private SwingWorker<BufferedImage, BufferedImage> bufferGenerator;

    public DrawTest() {
        resizeTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                buffer = null;

                if (bufferGenerator != null) {
                    bufferGenerator.cancel(true);
                }

                // Create buffer in background
                bufferGenerator = new BufferGeneratorWorker();
                bufferGenerator.execute();
            }
        });
        resizeTimer.setRepeats(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate();
        resizeTimer.restart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (buffer != null) {
            g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    protected class BufferGeneratorWorker extends SwingWorker<BufferedImage, BufferedImage> {

        @Override
        protected BufferedImage doInBackground() throws Exception {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            System.out.println("-- Started");
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 100000 && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                i++;
                g2d.drawLine(0, i, getWidth(), i);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
            System.out.println("-- Completed");
            return img;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                buffer = get();
                repaint();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fill all the squares with Ls");
                DrawTest FillSquare = new DrawTest();
                frame.add(FillSquare);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks in advance. For the first bullet, I am just trying to recreate a program that has quite a long paint time(in perspective to computers). For the last bullet, how can I fix the problem so the timer is actually stopping the componentResize from going nuts? Finally for the second and third bullets, I'm not sure what you're trying to say(most likely because my programming skills is just not on your level, I would greatly appreciate some code for the two bullets)

Comment: This is what I'm confused with them: how do you run paint()/paintComponent(). It requires a "Graphics input", and in my mind, they are not meant to be run in that way, instead they are ran by repaint().

Comment: *"how do you run paint()/paintComponent()"* - You don't. Swing uses a passive rendering engine, meaning that it will tell you when it wants something painted, which could occur for any number of reasons, many which you don't have control over.  You can make "suggestions" when you want something painted through `repaint`

Comment: For any reason, the repaint command, now with two loops(I changed it a little) seems to make the second loop run endlessly, like a repaint command...

Comment: I could add an extra counter on the outside, it works, but that seems a little weird